# rosbag tools for bag operation

Tags: rosbag, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recently started to work exhaustively with rosbag.
Also started with extracting videos out of it and also start writing my own tools for timestamp manipulation (which was a nice exercise btw).
But then I found that there already exist tools for all these task.
Before I start writing more tools for bag operations, I'd like to ask what other repositories/packages/tools exist.

**Edit:**
I put the (hopefully ever-growing list) into an answer, so that this question gets more attention
**Please send more suggestions!**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/293154/rosbag-tools-for-bag-operation/) by [tik0](https://answers.ros.org/users/26705/tik0/) on ROS Answers with karma: 220 on 2018-06-04

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stevejp](https://answers.ros.org/users/33828/stevejp/) on 2018-06-04**:
This [post](https://discourse.ros.org/t/qt-rosbag-exporter/4964) on ros discourse last week for "Qt rosbag exporter", which is a Qt based GUI for working with bag files.

**Comment by [tik0](https://answers.ros.org/users/26705/tik0/) on 2018-06-05**:
Just awesome! Thanks for the hint! I'll put it in the list.

**Comment by [lmathieu](https://answers.ros.org/users/30984/lmathieu/) on 2018-06-05**:
In a totally different technology (web based), there is https://marvhub.com and https://github.com/ternaris/marv-robotics who works on bag files for displaying informations on the web (the best example i found : https://marvhub.com/#/detail/q4mwxc3epkcqpqhiyoru7xclii )

**Comment by [tik0](https://answers.ros.org/users/26705/tik0/) on 2018-06-11**:
@Imathieu This is just mindblowing. Never thought of such possibilities! I will directly integrate this into my work! Thanks for this awesome tip.

**Comment by [PrieureDeSion](https://answers.ros.org/users/33799/prieuredesion/) on 2018-06-13**:
@tik0 if you are looking to manipulate/log simple text-based data, here's a little something I wrote: https://gist.github.com/PrieureDeSion/f9e185ec14556e905373c5be72718d6d

It may be of use for quick processing and extraction.

**Comment by [tik0](https://answers.ros.org/users/26705/tik0/) on 2018-06-28**:
Found another toolset from this post, which is able to trim and merge bag files: https://answers.ros.org/question/10683/is-there-a-way-to-merge-bag-files/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So the **hopefully ever-growing** list to work with bag files is as follows:

- Native rosbag
- http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag
- https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/tree/kinetic-devel/tools/rosbag/scripts
- http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Cookbook
- http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/rosbag/html/index.html
- bag tools
- http://wiki.ros.org/bag_tools
- rqt_bag
- http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_bag
- http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_bag_plugins
- rqt_bag_exporter
- https://gitlab.com/InstitutMaupertuis/rqt_bag_exporter
- https://discourse.ros.org/t/qt-rosbag-exporter/4964
- MARV Robotics (extensible data management platform)
- Code: https://github.com/ternaris/marv-robotics
- Example: https://marvhub.com/#/collection/bags
- Example: https://marvhub.com/#/detail/q4mwxc3epkcqpqhiyoru7xclii
- Matlab solutions
- native robotics toolbox: https://de.mathworks.com/help/robotics/ref/rosbag.html
- (tested and working well): https://github.com/unl-nimbus-lab/bag2matlab
- (untested): https://github.com/bcharrow/matlab_rosbag
- Various bag tools (trimming, merging, editing, ... bag files)
- bagtools: https://bitbucket.org/daniel_dube/bagedit/wiki/Home
- Rosbag Editor: https://github.com/facontidavide/rosbag_editor
- rosbag_fixer (work around message header's missing dependency information): https://github.com/gavanderhoorn/rosbag_fixer
- Thread on [Importing Rosbag in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59794328/importing-rosbag-in-python-3)
- Bag export to other formats
- This is not well supported. So the best way is to export the [bag to CSV](https://answers.ros.org/question/9102/how-to-extract-data-from-bag/) which can then be [converted using pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.14.1/io.html), for instance
- Thread on [rosbag to npz or h5 conversion](https://answers.ros.org/question/293151/rosbag-to-npz-or-h5-conversion/)

**Edit**

1. Added Matlab solutions
2. Add toolset for trimming and merging bag files
3. Add Rosbag Editor
4. Add rosbag_fixer
5. Add bag export

---

Originally posted by [tik0](https://answers.ros.org/users/26705/tik0/) with karma: 220 on 2018-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on 2018-06-28**:
As I found myself working more and more with rosbag files this is very useful, is there a place where we should put this list on the wiki?

**Comment by [tik0](https://answers.ros.org/users/26705/tik0/) on 2018-06-29**:
Also thought about that. But do you have anything in mind? From my point of view the ROS wiki might not be optimal, since this topic is very generic.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-07-18**:
Could add [gavanderhoorn/rosbag_fixer](https://github.com/gavanderhoorn/rosbag_fixer):

> Replaces incomplete msg defs with the correct ones in bags with topics published by rosjava

Works around [rosjava/rosjava_bootstrap#16](https://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_bootstrap/issues/16).

Would be better to have an actual fix committed, but that would depend on someone picking that issue up and actually solving it.